# ARM NEON Intrinsics in C

Tags: arm, intrinsics, neon

I'm writing an application for NEON. Where can I find the NEON ARM intrinsics in C/C++? 
I want to be able to decode my code running the application on a PC.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/neon/info has a couple links.  (I have no idea what you mean by *I want to be able to decode my code running the application on a PC*, though.  Code using NEON intrinsics can only be compiled for ARM or AArch64, so you'll need to run your code in an emulator on a PC.  And "decode my code" doesn't mean anything to me, I really don't know what you mean.)

Comment: Thanks Peter, and sorry if I was not clear.
I would like to have the equivalent of the intrinsics written in C, for example:
int16x4_t vadd_s16(int16x4_t a, int16x4_t b) {
  int16x4_t c;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
  }
  return c;
}

Comment: For `vadd_s16`, see https://github.com/nemequ/simde/blob/master/simde/arm/neon/int16x4.h#L52 .  I'm not making in an answer because I've barely started working on NEON… The best you're going to do is probably https://developer.arm.com/technologies/neon/intrinsics

Comment: Thanks nemequ for the second link, it's usefull to really understand in details each intrinsic

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively simulate NEON intrinsics on PC using this header file:
[NEONvsSSE.h](https://github.com/Ewenwan/MVision/blob/master/CNN/HighPerformanceComputing/example/optimination/NEONvsSSE.h)

In my experience it has close to 100% Arm/PC compatibility

In your solution it is possible to use definition like following to distinguish between Arm/PC versions:

```
#if !defined PC_VER
#include <arm_neon.h>
#else
#include "NEONvsSSE.h"
#endif
```

Comment: A more official link: https://github.com/intel/ARM_NEON_2_x86_SSE